# What's the point of this form at the back of some flight ticket asking for the passenger name?

Tags: usa, air-travel, tickets, paperwork

What's the point of this form at the back of some flight ticket asking for the passenger name?

[image]

I'm confused as the front of the flight ticket already mentions the passenger name. I forgot what flight route it was. I didn't have to complete the form: it was left empty.

Comment: How old is that ticket? Obviously this is all done electronically by now.

Comment: @jcaron not that old, pretty sure within the last 3 years.

Comment: Probably added that to tickets paper stock back in 1998 and then forgot to remove it from the templates later on. As for the reason to have the name on the back again, that probably makes input/lookup of the data easier by having everything on the same side.

Comment: Note that even 31 years after Unicode and almost 40 years after ECMA-94 and ISO 8859-1, computer systems still routinely mangle my name as to be almost unrecognizable or even refuse to accept it at all. More often than not, the name printed on the ticket has only a passing resemblance to my actual name to the point where I can't check in online, on my phone, or at a kiosk, with the only possibility to do it in person at a counter. Also, see https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/ The fact that *some* name is printed on the ticket does …

Comment: … not necessarily mean that is actually the traveller's name.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks, because of the umlaut?

Comment: Yup. The umlaut is the main problem when dealing with computers. A smaller problem is sometimes caused by the fact that my passport, ID card, and driver's license contain my full name (first, middle, last), professionally, I don't use my middle name, and privately, I use a middle initial but without the customary period. This can cause trouble if, for example, the travel agent my employer has on retainer book a flight using the name from our company address book rather than my passport (which they *do* have on file exactly for such use cases).

Comment: @JörgWMittag [If one's name contains an umlaut, can it be replaced with vowel without umlaut + e on a flight ticket? (e.g., Jürgen -> Juergen)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178649/1810)

Comment: @JörgWMittag What does the machine readable zone on your passport say? Jorg or Joerg?

Comment: I don't have my passport with me, but on my national ID card, the *name* field says `Jörg` and the MRZ says `JOERG`. I'm 99% sure the passport is the same.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Got it, from https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178649/1810, sounds like you could simply just use Joerg on flight tickets to avoid the umlaut issue.

Answer (score 6):

As the text says, this was added as a part of a 1998 [US Government regulation](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/FR-1998-02-18/98-3769) that required the airlines to collect the full name of all passengers, as well as to "solicit" contact details for an emergency contact.

Boarding passes at the time were always torn in half at boarding, with the airline keeping the larger part of the pass (along with the "coupon" from the ticket that would normally have been stapled onto the back of the boarding pass at check-in) - and the text above would have been printed on that part of the boarding pass so in effect the airline was collecting this information at boarding.

I do recall airlines asking passengers to fill in this information at the gate, however not for very many years, and I don't believe it was ever actually enforced (thus meeting the requirement to "solicit" this information, without an actual need to force it).

Obviously now days the passenger details are fully computerized, so the passenger name part of this form is not required (and arguably never was due to it being on the ticket anyway). However this form still met the requirements of "soliciting" emergency contact details, even if the airline knew that nobody every bothered to fill them in.

The requirement (with slightly different wording) still exists in the current [Code of Federal Regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-II/subchapter-A/part-243), and airlines must

> Solicit, or cause to be solicited, a name and telephone number of a
> contact from each passenger who is a U.S. citizen

Some airlines certainly do prompt for emergency contact information during online check-in, however I can't say that I've been asked for it at a check-in desk for some time so enforcement of this rule is seemingly fairly lax.  I suspect that somewhere in most airlines Contact of Carriage is a statement that you should provide emergency contact details, thus meeting the requirement without having the need for the airline to actually do anything!

Comment: Your linked rulemaking gives some useful background information: "During the immediate aftermath of the tragic bombing of Pan American Flight 103 over Lockerbie, Scotland on December 21, 1988, the Department of State experienced difficulties in
securing complete and accurate passenger manifest information and in notifying the families of the Pan American 103 victims. The Department of State did not receive the information for ‘'more than seven hours after the tragedy’'"