# If one's name contains an umlaut, can it be replaced with vowel without umlaut + e when booking a flight ticket? (e.g., Jürgen -> Juergen)

Tags: air-travel, tickets

Assume one's name contains an umlaut. I wonder whether one can replace the umlaut with vowel without umlaut + e when booking a flight ticket. E.g., Jürgen -> Juergen. Or will this cause some issue later, e.g. during check-in or immigration?

Comment: How does the alternative Jurgen (same spelling but just drop the umlaut) sit in this case? In a no umlaut in the language country it is seen as the more natural alternative.

Comment: @Willeke Good question, I don't know. My guess is that it would be fine in most cases, but no idea if there are some exceptions (e.g., in umlaut countries).

Comment: What does the machine readable zone on your passport say?

Answer (score 7):

Your best option is probably to check how your name is written in the [machine-readable zone (MRZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport#Names) (the 2 lines at the bottom of the bio page) and use that.

The spec allows both versions, but whether one or the other is used may depend on national policies.

The International Civil Aviation Organization guidelines for Machine Readable Travel Documents contains a [table of recommended transliterations](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf#page=32) for Unicode characters outside the range of `0-9`, `A-Z`, and `<`.

Comment: Thanks! "The spec allows both versions" -> MRZ spec?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport#Names

Comment: Thanks! I see that https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_cons_en.pdf#page=32 Section 6 has a few more transliterations.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally fine.

That's actually my German middle name and I've used Jurgen or Juergen without any problems.

Comment: Thanks, how do you decide using Jurgen vs. Juergen? Coin toss or depending on countries or some other factor? Also, does the machine readable zone on your passport say Jurgen or Juergen?

Comment: I normally go with Juergen which is also on the machine readable part of my passport. Jurgen often happens if I enter the Umlaut in some form that accepts it but the get dropped along the way.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Using "ue" for ü is a very German thing. In Finnish the umlauts are usually simply dropped, because "Maeaettae" for Määttä would be kind of ridiculous.